# Warning: oci_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in Oracle PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

hice un método para comprobar si el nombre de la póliza existe o no, pero siempre me regresa un booleano (siempre un true), y siempre es true, me gustaría saber como recupero el dato que necesito de una bd en oracle con oci.

**Este es mi código.**

```
 public function validarPoliza($poliza){

      try{
          $conexion_oracle = $this->conexionOci();
          $statement = oci_parse($conexion_oracle,"SELECT STATEMENT_NUMBER FROM CE_STATEMENT_HEADERS_INT WHERE STATEMENT_NUMBER ="."'".$poliza."'");
          $statement= oci_execute($statement);
          $r = oci_fetch($statement);
          $resultado = $r;
          return $resultado;

      }catch(Exception $e){
        $e->getMEssage();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de PHP, [oci_execute()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.oci-execute.php) y [oci_fetch()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch.php) siempre devuelve TRUE si puede hacer la consulta. El warning es porque estás asignando el valor de TRUE a $statement cuando invocas `oci_execute();` y luego lo estás tratando de pasar por el `oci_fetch();`
Para asignar el valor a alguna variable, tienes que hacer una definición antes de ejecutar el query.

```
$statement = oci_parse($conexion_oracle, "SELECT STATEMENT_NUMBER FROM ...");
oci_define_by_name($statement, 'STATEMENT_NUMBER', $st_numb);
oci_execute($statement);
oci_fetch($statement);
return $st_numb;
```

Otra forma, que me gusta más, es con [oci_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php)

```
$statement = oci_parse($conexion_oracle, "SELECT STATEMENT_NUMBER FROM ...");
oci_execute($statement);
$ora_row = oci_fetch_assoc($statement);
return $ora_row['STATEMENT_NUMBER'];
```

Comment: Gracias hermano! funcionó de maravilla, desconocia el oci_fetch_assoc y el ocide_define_by_name, sin duda son banstante interesantes. Saludos!

Comment: Se podría implementar consultas preparadas para evitar riesgos de Inyección SQL.